In mainstream post-Crisis continuity, when did Luthor boast to Lois about how he could end cancer and famine?
In Action Comics #837, the second issue of the 2006 storyline "Up, Up, and Away!", Lois alludes to a past conversation with Lex Luthor.

"He once told me that he believed he had the ability to cure cancer, to eliminate famine. But Superman was always in his way."

What comic issues did this talk between Lex and Lois originally happen in? It'd have to be sometime post-Crisis, between 1987 and 2006, which is a pretty wide net of continuity.

Lex cured cancer in Superman #149, way back in the 1940s

@Valorum Except pre-Crisis Luthor didn't boast to Lois that he hypothetically could cure cancer, he just said he would cure cancer, and then did it in under 24 hours. Promises made, promises kept.

Just because she said that does not necessarily mean it happened in any issue.  She could be remembering an ‘off screen’ conversation.  Or maybe it did, will see if anyone posts an answer of it happening.

@Valorum Superman #149 is a comic from 1961, not "the 1940s." And is definitely irrelevant to this question.

@user10063 - Gosh, well it's a good job I didn't post it as an answer then, merely as a comment.
